# Can you use ALT+TAB to switch to a child window?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a w32 program with c++. Is it possible to do something like:

1. Open a child window in the parent window, and the child gets the focus.
2. Use alt+tab to switch to another program.
3. Use alt+tab to switch back to the parent program and child window still has the focus.

What is happening right now is, at step 3, the parent gets the focus instead of the child.

One other tricky part is, I only have the handle of the parent window, and not full control. The program I am working on is a child window as a plugin for the parent.

Comment: There isn't any obvious reason why the child would lose the focus.  Work with whomever wrote the parent to get this resolved.

Comment: When a top-level window is activated, it is given focus. It is the parent window's decision whether to keep focus or to hand it to a child window. If you want to change the behavior of the parent window, you need to change the code in the parent window to change the behavior. (It's entirely possible that the parent window is intentionally *not* giving focus to the child for some reason, and you are now trying to circumvent the parent window's focus policy. That's why you need to coordinate with the parent window.)

Comment: Thanks guys, that's what I thought too :)